# Swing JList SetCellRenderer BackGround Color Not Working

Tags: java, swing, highlight, jlist, listcellrenderer

Good morning:

I have a JList in Swing with some data. I select the data from the DataBase and I am trying that the data that matches same in the JList be selected and in another colour, but I have tried all posibilities I could and gave me a lot of error. My code.

**This array saves the tags i would like to highlight.**

```
 final String[] segmentacion2 = suscriptor.getSegmentacion2().split(";");
```

**This for is to pre-select the tags.**

```
 for (int j = 0; j < segmentacion2.length; j++)
     {
         listaSegmentacion2.setSelectedValue(segmentacion2[j], true);
     }


     listaSegmentacion2.setCellRenderer(new DefaultListCellRenderer() {

         @Override
         public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList list,
                 Object value, int index, boolean isSelected,
                 boolean cellHasFocus) {

             super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
         for (int j = 0; j < segmentacion2.length; j++)
             {
                 listaSegmentacion2.setSelectedValue(segmentacion2[j], true);
             }

             System.out.println(isSelected);
             if(isSelected)
             {
                 setBackground(Color.green);
             }
             else
             {
                 setBackground(null);
             }
           return this;
         }
     });
```

And the error I got is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at javax.swing.UIDefaults.getFromHashtable(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.UIDefaults.get(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.MultiUIDefaults.get(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.UIManager.get(Unknown Source)
at sun.swing.DefaultLookup.get(Unknown Source)
at sun.swing.DefaultLookup.getBorder(Unknown Source)
at sun.swing.DefaultLookup.getBorder(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer.getNoFocusBorder(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer.getListCellRendererComponent(Unknown Source)
at com.mypackage.main.Principal$2.getListCellRendererComponent(Principal.java:509)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.updateLayoutState(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI.maybeUpdateLayoutState(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicListUI$Handler.valueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.fireValueChanged(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.changeSelection(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultListSelectionModel.setSelectionInterval(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JList.setSelectedIndex(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JList.setSelectedValue(Unknown Source)
```

Any suggestions/ help? Would be apreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] so we can also reproduce your exception. Please don't post your entire code, but create a small runnable example (maximum 100-150 lines of code). BTW: `setBackground(null)` looks ugly. Try `setBackground(list.getBackground())` instead.

Comment: BTW2: call of `setSelectedValue(Object)` in your renderer must be removed. I think - this is the main reason of your problems.

Comment: BTW3: If you only want to paint your selection with the green background, you can simply use the method `JList.setSelectionBackground(Color)` and completly remove your renderer.

Comment: That's what I needed. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

> This array saves the tags i would like to highlight.

Then you need to compare the data in the Array with the data being rendered.

The easiest way to do this is to copy the data from the Array to a Set:

```
HashSet<String> values = new HashSet<String>();

for (String value: segmentation2)
    values.add( value );
```

Now in the renderer the basic logic would be:

```
if (!isSelected)
    if (values.contains(value.toString())
        setBackground( Color.GREEN );
    else
        setBackground( null );
```

The idea is the highlighting is based on the value, not on the selection.

Comment: That's what I needed. Thank you so much!

Comment: @DeathGun, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.